# rospy.ServiceProxy master port mismatch

Tags: ros, roslaunch, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On my dev machine I run ros master on default port `11311` via `ROSLaunchParent` as follows:

```
os.environ["ROS_IP"] = "<dev-machine-ip>"
os.environ["ROS_MASTER_URI"] = "http://<dev-machine-ip>:11311"
roslaunch = ROSLaunchParent('', [], is_core=True, port=11311)
roslaunch.start()
```

stdout states that the roslaunch server is running on port `43121` (changes randomly between starts of roslaunch):

```
started roslaunch server http://<dev-machine-ip>:43121/
```

The master seems to be started on port `11311`:

```
auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [15304]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://<dev-machine-ip>:11311/
```

I use [`docker-py`](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) (`dc` is a `client`, `di` is an `images` instance, `dn` is a `network`) to run a ROS node `<some-node>` in a docker container which connects to the dev machines master.

```
dn = dc.networks.create(name='some_test', driver="bridge")
some_node = dc.containers.run(image=di[0].id, environment=["ROS_IP=<some-ip-in-the-dev-machine-subnet>", "ROS_MASTER_URI=http://<dev-machine-ip>:11311"], name='<some-node>', network='test', command=rosrun_command, detach=True, tty=True)
```

`import rosnode; nodes = rosnode.get_node_names(); print(nodes)` lists `/<some-node>` (and `/rosout`). `some-node` is (at least) discoverable in the network. So far so good.

If I send multiple service requests with

```
rc_itempick_start = rospy.ServiceProxy('/<some-node-namespace>/<some-service>', <service-type>)
rc_itempick_start()
```

a random port is used instead of `11311`:

```
core.py    WARNING  Unknown error initiating TCP/IP socket to <some-ip-in-the-dev-machine-subnet>:35516 (rosrpc://<some-ip-in-the-dev-machine-subnet>:35516)
(...)
error: [Errno 113] No route to host
core.py    WARNING  Unknown error initiating TCP/IP socket to <some-ip-in-the-dev-machine-subnet>:60739 (rosrpc://<some-ip-in-the-dev-machine-subnet>:60739)
(...)
error: [Errno 113] No route to host
(etc.)
```

Can someone help out in cross-checking what I missed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298858/rospy.serviceproxy-master-port-mismatch/) by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 468 on 2018-07-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-27**:
The port in the `rosrpc` URIs is not `11311` (or the port of the roslaunch server) because those URIs are not pointing to the master (or the roslaunch server), but to the port the service server uses to accept an incoming service request.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-27**:
after your edit:

> ```
> error: [Errno 113] No route to host
> ```

This points to your service server not having been configured with the correct value for either `ROS_IP` or `ROS_HOSTNAME`. Or if it is the correct IP, then the docker container can't reach it.

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-07-27**:
Right. I am not sure what to look at else w.r.t. service server config. I am not sure what the default docker network behaviour is. probably good to continue debugging here...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-27**:
The Python stuff you show seems to setup a `bridge`d network, so IPs in the `dev-machine-subnet` should probably work. Is `some-ip-in-the-dev-machine-subnet` in the `rosrpc` URI an expected value? Can you `ping` that IP from the container? If not, that would be the first thing to fix.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-27**:
Btw: I don't see you configuring the IP for the container to use. If the container uses a 'random' IP instead of the one you set in `ROS_IP`, then things probably won't work.

Edit: in fact, if the code sample you show is what you actually run I'm pretty sure that is the problem. The ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-27**:
.. container *must* have the same IP as you pass in for `ROS_IP`. Even if `test` is a `bridge`d network, handing out IPs from another subnet will most likely not work. You'll have to use IPs from the `test` network. Afaik, `bridged` for a Docker network is not like VMware's `bridged` (for example).

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-07-27**:
Right, totally missed that. When using docker-py setting the ip of the container explicitly requires to configuring the [network](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/networks.html#docker.models.networks.NetworkCollection.create) (subnets , etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I missed to configure the docker subnet configuration

```
ipam_pool = docker.types.IPAMPool(subnet='X.X.X.0/24')
ipam_config = docker.types.IPAMConfig(pool_configs=[ipam_pool])
dn = dc.networks.create(name='some_test', driver="bridge", ipam=ipam_config)
```

and a specific ip for the container

```
some_node = dc.containers.run(image=di[0].id, environment=["ROS_IP=<some-ip-in-the-dev-machine-subnet>", "ROS_MASTER_URI=http://<dev-machine-ip>:11311"], name='<some-node>', command=rosrun_command, detach=True, tty=True)
dn.connect(rc_itempick, ipv4_address='<some-ip-in-the-dev-machine-subnet>')
```

Have to do additional checks but seems to work now...

---

Originally posted by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) with karma: 468 on 2018-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-29**:
I'm surprised you can actually hand out IPs from a different subnet, but if it works for you ..

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-07-30**:
The ips have to be in the same subnet. Which different subnets do you mean? Have I missed a typo above...?